# Excel VLOOKUP between two sheets failing

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to copy data from column E (cost) in sheet1 where the value in column A (code) in sheet2 matches to the value in column A (code) on sheet1.

```
1
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+--------+
| A      | B      | C             | D       | E      |
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+--------+
| Code   | Name   | Description   | Price   | Cost   |
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+--------+
| AC33   | Prod 1 | Prod Desc 1   |  3.99   | 2.00   |
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+--------+
| AC34   | Prod 2 | Prod Desc 2   |  4.99   | 3.00   |
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+--------+
| AC35   | Prod 3 | Prod Desc 3   |  5.99   | 4.00   |
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+--------+

2

+--------+--------+---------------+---------+
| A      | B      | C             | D       |
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+
| Code   | Name   |Updated Price  | Cost    |
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+
| AC33   | Prod 1 |    16.99      |         | 
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+
| AC37   | Prod 2 |    18.99      |         |
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+
| AC38   | Prod 3 |    21.99      |         | 
+--------+--------+---------------+---------+
```

I have used a VLOOKUP but it isn't working, can anyone help please? Am I right in using Vlookup?

This is the formula I am dragging down in column D of sheet2

=VLOOKUP(A2,'1'!$A$2:$A$811,5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,'1'!$A$2:$E$811,5,0)`

I changed `'1'!$A$2:$A$811` to `'1'!$A$2:$E$811` (as mentioned @Jerry in the comment below, 
*"the table range you're using `VLOOKUP` on should contain both the column of lookup value and the column containing the result you wish to extract"*
) and I also specified last argument of `VLOOKUP` equals to `0`, which says `VLOOKUP` to find an exact match.

**UPD:**

As follows up from comments, next formula works for OP:

`=VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2),'1'!$A$2:$E$811,5,0)`

Comment: +1 For the explanation, the table range you're using `VLOOKUP` on should contain both the column of lookup value and the column containing the result you wish to extract.

Comment: Thankyou @simoco I knew I must have been missing something! Perhaps there is still an error in the formula though? I am still getting #N/A in each cell

Comment: try to check, maybe you have some extra spaces in column A (in sheet 1 or in sheet 2, i.g. `"AC38 "` instead `"AC38"`) and also try `=VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2),'1'!$A$2:$E$811,5,0)`

Comment: The trim function did it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Below are some of the best practices which resolved the issue.

1) Use the dollar symbol for arguments

2) Provide the complete options

**Syntax**

VLOOKUP('Lookupvalue','Table Array','Column Index','Range Lookup')

**Please note** 
range_lookup  TRUE = approximate match and is by default whereas FALSE = exact match. 
Please make it false or 0 if you are looking for an exact match.TRUE value relies on your data being sorted in ascending order to work.

**Example**

    VLOOKUP($A1,SheetName!$A:$G,2,0)

Enjoy!!!